# Lazy initialization of OnetoOne mapping when update fired for second time

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to understand why when I hit the controler for second time, My OnetoOne Mapping is getting lay initialized. Below is my code:
Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updateOrderbyOrderid", method=RequestMethod.PUT,produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Order updateOrderbyOrderid (@RequestBody Order orderVO ) {

System.out.println(orderVO.getOrderId());
Order s1 = orderRepository.findByOrderId(orderVO.getOrderId());
if (orderVO.getCustomerId()!=null) {
    orderVO.setCustomer(customerRepository.findByCustomerId(orderVO.getCustomerId()));
}

s1 = orderRepository.saveAndFlush(orderVO);

return s1;
}
```

Order Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Ordertable", schema="cf_2583f365_c3c6_499a_a60d_138e7e7023eb")
public class Order {
@Id
@Column(name = "ORDER_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int orderId;



@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_CUSTOMER_ID", referencedColumnName = "CUSTOMER_ID")
private Customer customer;

private transient Long customerId;


public int getOrderId() {
    return orderId;
}

public void setOrderId(int orderId) {
    this.orderId = orderId;
}

public Customer getCustomer() {
    return customer;
}

public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
}


public Long getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
}

public void setCustomerId(Long customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
}

}
```

Customer Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Customer", schema="cf_2583f365_c3c6_499a_a60d_138e7e7023eb")
public class Customer {

@Id
@Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long customerId;

@Column(name = "CUSTOMER_NAME")
private String customer_name;


@Column(name = "CUSTOMER_address_id")
private int customer_address_id;


public Long getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
}


public void setCustomerId(Long customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
}


public String getCustomer_name() {
    return customer_name;
}


public void setCustomer_name(String customer_name) {
    this.customer_name = customer_name;
}


public int getCustomer_address_id() {
    return customer_address_id;
}


public void setCustomer_address_id(int customer_address_id) {
    this.customer_address_id = customer_address_id;
}


public Customer() {

}

}
```

Json structure for Controller:

```
{
    "orderId" :101,
    "customerId" : 2
}
```

Order Table for First Hit :

[image]

OnetoOne annotated entity screenshot for first hit. No lazy initialised bean for customerRepository.findByCustomerId(orderVO.getCustomerId()):

[image]

Order Table for Second Hit :

[image]

When I hit for second time, I get a lazy loaded bean for customerRepository.findByCustomerId(orderVO.getCustomerId()). Why is it happening:

[image]

My expectation is hibernate should get fully loaded bean for next time as well when I am doing orderVO.setCustomer(customerRepository.findByCustomerId(orderVO.getCustomerId())); rather than assiging the lazy initialised bean which it got from Order s1 = orderRepository.findByOrderId(orderVO.getOrderId());

One important  Note, If I comment below line in controller:

```
Order s1 = orderRepository.findByOrderId(orderVO.getOrderId()); :
```

and replace it with Order s1 = null, I am not getting lazy initialised bean anymore. Was hibernate **caching** the same lazy initialised bean internally earlier ??

Screenshot of s1 when I didn't commented it :
[image]

Code after commenting s1 & replacing it with null:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updateOrderbyOrderid", method=RequestMethod.PUT,produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Order updateOrderbyOrderid (@RequestBody Order orderVO ) {
System.out.println(orderVO.getOrderId());
Order s1 = null;
//Order s1 = orderRepository.findByOrderId(orderVO.getOrderId());
if (orderVO.getCustomerId()!=null) {
    orderVO.setCustomer(customerRepository.findByCustomerId(orderVO.getCustomerId()));
}

s1 = orderRepository.saveAndFlush(orderVO);

return s1;
}
```

Comment: What is your expectation?

Comment: My expectation is hibernate should get fully loaded bean for next time as well when I am doing orderVO.setCustomer(customerRepository.findByCustomerId(orderVO.getCustomerId())); rather than assiging the lazy initialised bean which it got from Order s1 = orderRepository.findByOrderId(orderVO.getOrderId());

Comment: Try to create a `OrderVO` class as a simple POJO (with no Hibernate annotations) containing only `customerId` and `orderId` fields and use it to collect the JSON values. Then use this values to get `Order` and `Customer` from the repositories. I think it's not a good idea to use managed entities to collect the JSON values, the managed entities must be used only for persistence.

Comment: @JMSilla I had tried this one as well, but got same result. You can also try this thing on your PC.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data JPA - `findBy()` method is internally implemented by `EntityManager.find()`. `EntityManager.find()` first checks the Data in cache, if no data is found in cache then hits DB to load data & puts in cache to make it managed.

If we again do `EntityManager.find()` (again for same primary key), it checks cache again. Now this time data is loaded from cache rather than hitting DB.

I think Hibernate is caching the Object, and when I hit second time it returns proxy object for cached item.

Below are the links I have read to understand `findBy()` working.

[When use getOne and findOne methods Spring Data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482117/when-use-getone-and-findone-methods-spring-data-jpa)

[similar load and get hibernate method on spring data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362771/similar-load-and-get-hibernate-method-on-spring-data)

[What is the difference between EntityManager.find() and EntityManger.getReference()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482141/what-is-the-difference-between-entitymanager-find-and-entitymanger-getreferenc)

Now to test whether I am right or not, I used `em.detach()` in my below code. `detach()` will make managed entity --> unmanaged and also remove it from cache. Now when I execute the code, I got newly initialised bean.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updateOrderbyOrderid", method=RequestMethod.PUT,produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Order updateOrderbyOrderid (@Valid @RequestBody Order orderVO ) {
    
    System.out.println(orderVO.getOrderId());
    Order s1 = orderRepository.findByOrderId(orderVO.getOrderId());
    em.detach(s1.getCustomer());
    s1= null;
    if (orderVO.getCustomerId()!=null) { 
        Customer findByCustomerId = customerRepository.findByCustomerId(orderVO.getCustomerId());
        orderVO.setCustomer(customerRepository.findByCustomerId(orderVO.getCustomerId()));
    }

    s1 = orderRepository.saveAndFlush(orderVO);
    
    return s1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to use **fetch=FetchType.EAGER** for OneToOne mapping

```
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_CUSTOMER_ID", referencedColumnName = "CUSTOMER_ID")
private Customer customer;
```

hope it will help.

Comment: I am using spring data jpa to fetch data, not directly using hibernate entity manager. So eager will have no effect on it. See this URL : https://stackoverflow.com/q/56248867/4860775 . Also try it on your PC.

Comment: 1:1 is by default EAGER.

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping looks a lot like ManyToMany. Try this out:

```
// OrderTable
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_ID", nullable = false)
private Customer customer;
// constructors
public OrderTable() {}
public OrderTable(Customer customer) { this.customer = customer; }


// Customer
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "customer")
private OrderTable orderTable;
```